# Applying for jobs out of province?

Tags: interviewing, applications, relocation, canada

I have been trying to relocate from one province to another. Currently, I am vacationing in the province I would like to work in and I have received an email from a job application I sent out.

The HR manager told me to contact her again the next time I am in the province and she will let me know if the position has been filled since the interviewing process has not begun, which I believe means they only want face-to-face interviews and not phone/Skype. She does not know I am currently in the province.

I am leaving next wednesday to go back home (it seems inappropriate of me to ask if I can have an interview before then) and I was hoping to secure a job before making the big move. Is this even possible when most employers don't do phone interviews? and how should I respond to her email?

Comment: Tell the truth. You are currently vacationing, soon leaving, though are looking to move to the province. Is it possible to get an early interview before you are leaving? Strike while the iron is hot.

Comment: How far apart are the locations between where you are now and home?  If the distance is low enough then it may be possible to do a face-to-face interview, no?

Comment: Unfortunately it is on the opposite end of the country.

Comment: What country? I'd assume Canada, but nice to know for sure.

Comment: Yes it is Canada, from Ontario to BC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this answer is being posted after this situation is resolved, I'll post for future searchers.

There can be difficulties with interviewing under the circumstances you describe.

- If you expected to be casually dressed for your entire vacation, you probably did not pack formal clothes.  You may be able to ask the organization if they expect formal attire for interviewees.  If they do, some quick clothes shopping will likely be in order; perhaps a thrift store will be able to save you money.
- You may have to change your vacation plans to spend time researching the potential employer, instead of seeing the sights or spending time relaxing.  If you aren't willing to make these sacrifices during your vacation, then I recommend that you avoid scheduling an interview during your vacation.  While you may want to reply quickly, I'd also say you probably want to avoid telling them that you're close by.  Just say you can't interview until whatever date you expect to be available.

Having said that, it should be to your advantage, if you are able to schedule an interview before you leave the area:

- While it is serendipitous that you happen to be in the place to which you want to re-locate when an opening is available, moving forward will show you as a proactive person.  While it may seem silly or even superstitious, for some people, the serendipity may may seem like you are "fated" for the job.
- On the other hand, if you wait to return home and the potential employer learns you were recently in the area, they may take an unfavorable view of you.
- The employer may not want to pay the travel expense for you to interview with them.  Thus, such employers often don't want to interview out-of-town candidates, but if you are already in the area, they may figure it doesn't hurt to interview you .
- By being the first to interview, if you do well, you will set yourself up as the standard that other candidates will be compared against.
- Practically speaking, if they call you in for an interview after you have returned home, you will have to explain to your current employer why you need more time off so soon after a vacation.  Interviewing while you are on vacation will avoid this issue.